# status of approval mail doesn´t change if in person field is a group as approver

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, approval-process

In my flow people can choose also groups as approver. everything works as expected just the mail in the inbox of the approvers doesn´t change in approved o rejected after approval.

If the approver is a person it´s ok.

that's with a person as approver (if rejected):

[image]

That's if a group member approves (after approval):

[image]

If I click again to approve it states that approval is  no longer active what's ok, but the status of the mail should change in approved or rejected.

Answer (score 0):

From this article [Get started with approvals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/get-started-approvals), It seems that you have to assign approvals to users instead of group.
[image]

Comment: i don´t think that this is the reason.
approvals are working with groups. the members of the group receive the approval email and it one of them approves it works.
it´s just that the email itself istn´t updated like when individual approvers approves the item.